# Where to find MQ Explorer logs on Mac

Tags: ibm-mq

This is a FAQ which I am going to answer myself.

If you have MQ Explorer running on a Mac you will notice that there are on occasion silent errors which manifest as system hangs.

Is there a way to capture logs to determine what is causing the hang / error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start MQExplorer from the command line. For me, because I installed in directory `~/Documents/dev/eclipse/MQExplorer` as `Eclipse415MQExplorer` this is from the directory -

```
~/Documents/dev/eclipse/MQExplorer/Eclipse415MQExplorer.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Start MQ Explorer by running

```
./eclipse
```

This will capture the logs, and any exceptions thrown to the terminal, which you could also pipe to a file.